# Regex for matching up to a total of x digits where of those x digits, at most y can be after the decimal

Tags: regex

I'm currently writing a validator where I need to check the formats of floats. My code reads in a format of (x,y) where x is the total possible digits in the float and y is the maximum digits out of x that can be after the decimal point. Apologies if this question has already been answered before, but I wasn't able to find anything similar.

For example, given a format of (5,3):

Valid values

```
55555
555.33
55.333
5555.3
.333
```

Invalid values

```
55555.5
555555
5.5555
.55555
```

This is my first time working with regex so if you guys have any tutorials that you recommend, please send it my way!

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lookahead to ensure both conditions, like

```
^(?=(?:\.?\d){1,5}$)\d*(?:\.\d{1,3})?$
```

- `^` match from the start of the string
- `(?=(?:\.?\d){1,5}$)` check for the presence of 1 up to 5 digits to the end of the string - not caring to much about the correct number of dots
- `\d*` match any number of digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,3})?` match up to 3 decimal places
- `$` ensure end of the string

See https://regex101.com/r/lrP56w/1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming JS you can try

```js
function validate(value, total, dec) {
  let totalRegex = new RegExp(`\\d{0,${total}}$`);
  let decimalRegex = new RegExp(`\\.\\d{0,${dec}}$`);
  return totalRegex.test(value.replace(".","")) && (!(/\./.test(value)) || decimalRegex.test(value));
}

console.log(validate("555.55", 5, 2));
console.log(validate("55.555", 5, 2));
console.log(validate("5.5", 5, 2));
console.log(validate("55555", 5, 2));
console.log(validate("5.5555", 5, 2));
```

Comment: The OP never mentioned javascript.  You should ask the OP what language/environment they are working in before making an assumption.